# Get only 70% of the post content

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on WP based RSS aggregation website and my code currently fetches all the content from the external site. Now, I'm trying to show up only 70% of the full post content so that I can link back the original content. Suppose postID 1 has 350 words and postID 2 has 600 words, I want the content to be 245 words for postID 1 and 420 for postID 2 respectively (both should show  70% of the available content). Any customized version of the following code should be working for me:

`<?php the_content(); ?>`

Comment: I have flagged your question as unclear. Nothing about your question makes any sense to anyone who has never looked at your code. Also, posting code of a function name is completely useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate `functions.php` in your theme directory and add a filter to your content:

```
<?php   

add_filter("the_content", "plugin_strip");

function plugin_strip($content) {
    $length = strlen($content);
    $max_length = intval($length * 0.7);
    return substr($content, 0, $max_length);
}
```

Or another method:

```
<?php

$content = get_the_content();
$length = strlen($content);
echo substr($content, 0, intval($length * 0.7));
```

Comment: Hi, I always did this in the other way and now it gives me only 40 words: 
 `<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 40 , '...' );?>` is there anyway I could rectify this to get 70% ie: 0.7 * length?